# How to put svg and button side by side and vertically align them?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have the following snippet:

```css
.float-left {
  float: left !important;
}

.float-right {
  float: right !important;
}

.container {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}

.has-border {
  border: 2px solid #000;
}

.d-inline-block {
  display: inline-block !important;
}

.align-middle {
  vertical-align: middle !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="has-border">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="div1 float-left">
      Contact
    </div>
    <div class="div2 float-right">
      <button class="d-inline-block">
      Hey
    </button>
      <svg width="20" height="20">
      <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="40"
      stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
    Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
    </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the button and the svg are side by side but are not vertically aligned.

So, how can I put the svg and button side by side which is also perfectly aligned vertically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) to align the items and cleaned up you code a little.

```css
.container {
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* vertical alignment */
}

.has-border {
  border: 2px solid #000;
}

.div2 {
  margin-left: auto; /* Pushes it to the right */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* vertical alignment */
}
```

```html
<div class="has-border">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="div1">
      Contact
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
      <button>
      Hey
    </button>
      <svg width="20" height="20">
      <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="40"
      stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
    Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
    </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Gerard

Answer (score 2):

Remove `float-left` and `clearfix` class and add `display: flex;` to `.float-right` and `display: flex; align-items:center;` to `.container`

```css
.float-right {
  margin-left: auto;
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.has-border {
  border: 2px solid #000;
}

.d-inline-block {
  display: inline-block !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="has-border">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="div1">
      Contact
    </div>
    <div class="div2 float-right">
      <button class="d-inline-block">
        Hey
      </button>
      <svg width="20" height="20">
        <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="40"
        stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
      Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `display:flex;` and  `align-items:center;` for class .float-right as shown below:

```
.float-right {
  float: right;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```css
.float-left {
  float: left;
}

.float-right {
  float: right;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}

.container {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}

.has-border {
  border: 2px solid #000;
}

.d-inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
}

.align-middle {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="has-border">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="div1 float-left">
      Contact
    </div>
    <div class="div2 float-right">
      <button class="d-inline-block">
      Hey
    </button>
      <svg width="20" height="20">
      <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="40"
      stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
    Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
    </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: also there is no need to use **!important**

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the button's css:

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

And to the svg:

```
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
```